# submit button click

Tags: c#, javascript, form-submit

I have GUI for data acceptance.
I need to pass all the parameters of the form on click of a submit button to a function declared in C#.
Please help.

Comment: You need to explain a little *(read a lot)* more and show some code where we can help.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET, if so it might be helpful if you post some code?

Comment: in my GUI i have made provision for entering the user details viz name, address, age. i have provided a button on the form which on click should assign all the details to the members declared in the class

Comment: in c sharp private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             
        }
 i need to write a function declaration in this to help the members of the class get the value entered in the text boxes...

Answer (score 0):

If your using asp.net you just need to double click the button(if it is an asp button) and it should make a click event.

In the click event you could get your other controls like

default.aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    // you can declare it as a field variable so the entire code behind can use it
    private Passengerdetails myClass;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // create an instance of the class.
       myClass = new Passengerdetails ();
       // stick textbox1 contents in the property called test.
       myClass.PassengerName = TextBox1.Text;


       int a =  Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
       int b = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
       int sum = Add(a, b);

       // do something with it like return it to a lbl.
       Label1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }

    private int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Edit. You just make a class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for passengerdetails 
/// </summary>
public class Passengerdetails 
{
    public Passengerdetails ()
    {

       public string PassengerName{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: hey thank you i got my answer  but is this the only way friend
and how should be my function declaration???

Comment: hey i m sorry didnt mention i want that in c sharp
m making an airlines reservation project 
taking in input of the user details via form1 say
i have a class say passengerdetails with class variables now
on click of the button i need to assign all those text box values to the class variables

Comment: ic what will you do once you have them in the class? Ok see my post I made a class and added something that would be in a textbox to a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using .Net us have too types of submit tags, one starting with `<asp:` and the other starting with `<input`. the <input html tag can call javascript and if you add the `runat="server"` attribute, you will enable it to also have C# code behind the button.

Comment: hey friend i don't need for asp.net 
in c sharp i want to get the details entered in the text boxes into the variables of the class on click of a button on the GUI...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to create an aspx page (say `submission.aspx`) that will receive the POST submission of your form. In that page, you can include your `.cs` file that contains the method/function you want to pass the data to.

Next, you want to submit you submit your data to `submission.aspx`. To do that, you will need to have a form which will submit its data to `submission.aspx`.

```
<form action='submission.aspx' method='POST' id='data-submission'>
    <!-- stuff here -->
</form>
```

If you want to perform ajax submission, you can use jquery and use this code:

```
$('#data-submission').submit(function(evt){
    var $form = $(this);
    var url = $form.attr('action');
    $.post(url, $form.serialize(), function(){alert('submission complete!);});
});
```

I wonder if all that helped you.

PS: I haven't used .NET for web programming in a long time now.. but what I've written here in this answer hold universally true for any web programming language/framework.